# Middle click closes tab in 19.04

Tags: lubuntu

I just installed Ubuntu 19.04 and I have a problem. When I click my touchpad on the middle and the pointer is on a tab, it closes the current tab. How can I disable this? It's very annoying. Also middle click paste is enabled even though I've disabled it from Tweaks.

Comment: isn't this middle click closes the tab the default on all OS? Afaik, it's not from the OS, but the browser. How to disable middle click paste as been asked here before. Please ask only one question at a time.

Comment: In Windows it did when I used a mouse, not while using the touchpad.

Comment: Indeed, also for me, middle click on touchpad closes the tab. However, middle-click with mouse doesn't.

Comment: Did you resolve this?